Spring Security with Spring Session can't correctly find the session after application restart
I'm implementing Spring Security with Spring Session for my cloud based application.
Everything works correctly, the integration with Spring Session as well. But if I restart my application (For example when creating new nodes on the cloud). The session cannot be found, causing the application to not work, unless I logout first (which sometimes also doesn't work).
Am I missing some configuration?
At the moment the application cannot be considered as completed.
Using:

Spring Cloud Gateway (servlet)


Oauth


Spring Session (JDBC)

Config:
      @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(e->e.authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults())
 //               .sessionManagement(sm->sm.maximumSessions(2).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()))
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oidcLogout(logout -> logout.backChannel(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(exchange ->
                        exchange.requestMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .logout(logout ->
                        logout
                                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }


Can you please show also the sessionRegistry method body?

@FrancescoPoli sorry, I was debugging and forgot to remove it. I think that Spring session should already handle this kind of stuff? I assume something crucial is still saved in memory which causes the authorization to fail when restarting the app.

I suppose you already checked everything is listed in the documentation page (https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/configuration/jdbc.html). This happens also locally, running the gateway and restarting it on your machine? Have you also checked what is stored on the session table on the db?

@FrancescoPoli Yes, but I'm using the Spring Boot config, so the JDBC & Spring Session should also be configured out-of-the-box (except for store-type, timeout, schema and table-name). The issue also happens locally. The session in the DB is correctly stored and removed when needed.
